# Jquery retrieving options from listbox [mysql]

Tags: jquery, mysql, listbox

I have a table named products with a name and price.

I have a list box `select name = listbox[] id = listbox` etc

When something is added to the listbox I want a price next to listbox to update by referencing the price from mysql table called products.

like updated on the same page without reload.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this    $.post("YourPage.php",{ parameters : Variable } , function(data) {

});

do all your Update Instruction with php and SQL in the page "YourPage.php"

and You have to passe some parameters to your page and Get the parameters by using

the Return value is " data " wich passes to the function return there value from php file

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/  take a look at this documentation it will help you

good luck buddy ...